# Ruby interpolating into variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, interpolation, string-interpolation

This is a hard question for me to even ask so I'll share the code first:

```
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          We operate on a pay what you want model. Keep in mind that 
          <% if action_name == "outdoors" %>
            <%= outdoors_donation.html_safe %>
          <% elsif action_name == "snowsports" %>
            <%= snowsports_donation.html_safe %>
          <% end %>
          Below, you'll find information on how we calculated your order's suggested donation of $<span id="modal-sentence"></span>.
        </div>
```

Rather than the clunky if statement, I'd rather just be able to inject action_name directly into the variable that's being called.... something like

```
<%= "#{action_name}_donation".html_safe %>
```

But not sure what this would actually be

Thanks!

Comment: Are your variables (outdoors_donation and snowsports_donation) instance variables?

Comment: You could keep the values in a hash and use the variable as the key, e.g. `donations[action_name]`.

Comment: YES a hash duh... ugh narrow minded ness will be the death of me, THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `send` in ruby to send a method that you provide the name for. This allows you to do interpolation:

```
<%= self.send("#{action_name}_donation").html_safe %>
```

In this context `self` would be the view instance which is the same as calling `outdoors_donation.html_safe` or `snowsports_donation.html_safe` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to go with the hash though because it feels much cleaner to me, but this is great as well!

Comment: Yeah, my answer addresses the question but I think the hash approach is probably a better to solution to the actual problem.